# conditional testing within cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am new to testing within cypress and I am trying to test the outcome of a div, it is driven by a conditional statement based up a users selection however I need to test to see which one appears, ofcourse I could write two different tests but I thought there must be an easier way to achieve this.

```
  cy.get('[data-test="attachments-table"]').as('attachmentsTable');
  cy.get('@attachmentsTable')
    .find('tr>th')
    .eq(4)
    .should('contain', 'FOIA');
  //cy.get('@attachmentsTable').find('[data-test="not-viewable-on-foia"]');
  cy.get('@attachmentsTable').find('[data-test="viewable-on-foia"]');
});

the commented line of code is what I would also like to test, how could I do this?
```

Comment: Where is your user selection? You have two expected outcome here. Shouldn't be simply like userselection1; result1; userselection2; result2?

Comment: How do you know you've tested both scenarios if you don't have two tests which cover each case? Conditional logic in order to navigate the UI is excusable, conditional assertions really don't make sense